# DevTools remote debugging at chrome not working normally with headless-chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug headless chrome without a browswer UI like [this reference](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#frontend)

My chrome version is  84.0.4147.105, and chromedriver version is also 84.

When I run headless-chrome, below notice appear at cmd

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9224/devtools/browser/~~
```

And When I enter `127.0.0.1:9224` at chrome, it works normally until yesterday.

But today, when I enter address, below strings shows up.

How can I solve this? No code has been changed before and after.

[image: Error Image]

> ���TQo�0~ϯ���$���li51����manri̜8�������m::��8>�w�ww�%�)��K
> `.�ӏ��5QPJ$�e�Z�j����K�Y���?hI���Ke� ����o-+2!a�DD&���v�)� �5�غ�Qt�yyS��#HH��g���x�t1W`>s'��O�B�}�0p�Js��:�;
> ���%�3!�YO1X�bk�4|�����3��j���n��c'��k�̂���͸'�H�tq��KfKI�z^����|����������v��h4{��wz�\��(n���gu
> Uv�;g9��Qn��\W^=X�wg�)���de���~��0�L�M
> ��S����}�5���)r"B�b�Ԃ�ҟs�;�S: ��r�
> r�r_S�J�{�`��cLZ�ʒjP-�ʹzu���o��愈���L��л����m�ᖀ��e������aK���ma��v�x��'�-���u�6��<�q�`�9
> �ϵ�������)O?l*�Y�D���㽷��w�&N���4�K�>��l�l�K��-�O^�G1��w�jݕ�.��B�N���*Qwu���6^��pr��w��,���GG��=2���Lh?��'+;�&�aSdH���=e�}�����5�X=�8;��ꄢ��i��AB-�cu��/:Y

What I want is like below image

[image]

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB I add image what I want. At no-headless works fine, but at headless not works

Comment: It's not just you -  I had this working a couple of weeks ago and now i get the same issue. I think it's chrome bug, but i can't find any reference to it at the moment

Comment: is it solved? If it was widespread, it should have been solves till now? I am stuck.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta No, not yet. I send email to devtools developer, but not read

Comment: Upvote the issue here - https://crbug.com/1121054

Comment: @BhavyaGupta It works after updating chrome with 85.0.4183.83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hit exactly the same wall as you and the same garbled response. I thought it was a bug - even after reboots it didn't come back so i was quietly waiting for a patch.

I just had a more detailed look now and - *AT A GUESS* - it seems to be related to the open chrome instances....
When i launch the new chrome with the remote debugging tag it attached to an existing chrome not in its own browser.

What i did:

Run these two commands to close all your chrome/chromedriver instances (including this one if you're using chrome - so use something else or copy it to notepad):

```
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe
taskkill /F /IM chromedriver.exe
```

Then run:

```
chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 --disable-gpu https://www.google.com
```

then- Open a new window and, for me, i was able to connect again.
Connect here: `http://127.0.0.1:9222/`

And get this... This is different to what i used to see.
Even though i ran headless, i still have my other windows (inc this message!) and my extensions.

[image]

Selecting the stack overflow window just for fun  just about make out me typing this reply in the body of the remote window:

[image: stack in remote debug]

As i type this now, my mouse has become locked as the remote cursor "blob" - so there is still some buggyness to it. However this worked for me to get this gets it back online.

Chrome version:
`Version 84.0.4147.105 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **chrome://inspect** in a new tab

2.click on configure button in the Devices section (Refer below image)

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWVZB.png)

3. Add your host address in Target discovery Settings and click **done**.
4. Now you may be able to see the remote chrome pages under **Remote Target** section (Refer below image)

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMID3.png)

Click inspect in it. Now you may able to inspect and debug the headless chrome page

Comment: Hmm... Since Chrome version 100, 127.0.0.1:port not working.. only works what you say